# TCP error on reply

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I created a simple network game that uses TCP sockets in order to get the other player's data. I have two different classes, a server and a client. Everything was perfectly fine when I was only sending one message at a time like so:

Client:

```
public void ClientTester()
{
    thread = new Thread(SendPosition);
    thread.Start();
}

private void SendPosition()
{
    while (true)
    {
        using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
        {
            client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 82);
            using (NetworkStream n = client.GetStream())
            {
                BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(n);
                w.Write("Position:" + GameFiles.Player.Player.position.ToString());
                w.Flush();
                string msg = new BinaryReader(n).ReadString();
                parseString(msg, "Position:", 9);
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(60);
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public void ServerTester()
{
    thread = new Thread(TheadedMethod);
    thread.Start();
}

private void TheadedMethod()
{
    while (true)
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 82);
        listener.Start();
        using (TcpClient c = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
        using (NetworkStream n = c.GetStream())
        {
            parseString(msg, "Position:", 9);
            BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(n);
            w.Write("Position:" + GameFiles.Player.Player.position.ToString());
            w.Flush();
        }
        listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

Here is the new code:

Client:

```
public void ClientTester()
{
    thread = new Thread(SendPosition);
    thread.Start();

    SendMousePosition();
}

private void SendPosition()
{
    while (true)
    {
        using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
        {
            client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 82);
            using (NetworkStream n = client.GetStream())
            {
                BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(n);
                w.Write("Position:" + GameFiles.Player.Player.position.ToString());
                w.Flush();
                string msg = new BinaryReader(n).ReadString();
                parseString(msg, "Position:", 9);
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(60);
    }
}

private void SendMousePosition()
{
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
    {
        client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 82);
        using (NetworkStream n = client.GetStream())
        {
            BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(n);
            w.Write("MousePosition:" + cursor.mousePosition());
            w.Flush();
            string msg = new BinaryReader(n).ReadString();
            parseString(msg, "MousePosition:", 14);
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public void ServerTester()
{
    thread = new Thread(TheadedMethod);
    thread.Start();
}

private void TheadedMethod()
{
    while (true)
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 82);
        listener.Start();
        using (TcpClient c = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
        using (NetworkStream n = c.GetStream())
        {
            string msg = new BinaryReader(n).ReadString();
            if (msg == "Position:")
            {
                parseString(msg, "Position:", 9);
                BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(n);
                w.Write("Position:" + GameFiles.Player.Player.position.ToString());
                w.Flush();
            }
            if (msg == "MousePosition:")
            {
                parseString(msg, "MousePosition:", 14);
                BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(n);
                w.Write("MousePosition:" + cursor.mousePosition());
                w.Flush();
            }
        }
        listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

When I try to send two messages in I receive an error:

```
Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.
```

on this line from the client's method SendPosition():

```
string msg = new BinaryReader(n).ReadString();
```

Why doesn't this work even though I have created a new instance of BinaryReader? Shouldn't the server automatically respond to each message sent to it?

Comment: please see msg value, for first time, i think two message will marge in one ReadString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing *two* things wrong: The fist is that you create and re-create the connection all the time. Instead create the listener once, enter the loop and read messages. Setting up a new connection in TCP ads a lot of overhead, especially if you're just sending small messages. Same thing in the client, connect once, and then send when needed.

The second problem is that TCP is a *streaming* protocol, and that there is no message boundaries. That means that when you read from a TCP connection you can't know beforehand how much data you will read, you need to provide a way to separate messages yourself: You can add message boundaries, you can prepend each message with a header containing the message size, of you have have all messages being the same fixed size. Either way, you might have to read multiple times to get a complete message, or one read could give you more than one message.

Regarding the second problem, you can't of course attempt to read more than have been received, which is probably what the error message is telling you.